# Help with jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I figured enough jQuery to select this chunk out of a huge HTML document. I want to select the value of subject, `body`, and `date_or_offset`. (these are `name` attributes as shown below). How do I go about this. Assuming this print is from `alert($(this).html())` inside a call back function.

```
<p><label for="first">Subject</label>  <br>
   <input class="input" name="subject" type="text">
</p>
<p><label for="textarea">Body </label> <br>
   <textarea class="textarea" name="body" id="textarea" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>  
</p>
<p><label for="first">Date <span>(xx/xx/xxxx) or Offset</span></label>  <br>
   <input class="input" name="date_or_offset" id="first" type="text">
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it via [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
var subject = $(this).find('input[name=subject]').val();
var body = $('#textarea').val();
var date = $('#first').val();
```

Since IDs are unique, the last 2 can be selected via a `#ID` selector directly, the first we find by `name="subject"` using an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).  If the IDs *aren't* unique (and they should be, fix it if that's the case) you can use a simular `[name=xx]` selector for the others, just use `textarea` instead of `input` for the `body` element.

Comment: Is the `find` really necessary?

Comment: @Gert - It depends he has an element, without more context you can't say for sure...but it's more efficient in any case.  A `$('input[name=subject]')` is *really* calling `$(document).find('input[name=subject]')` which searches the entire document, this searches a much narrower scope, so it's a much faster selector.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[name=subject]").val();
$("#textarea").val();
$("#first").val();
```